# Initialization in while block?

Tags: java

Isn't there a cleaner way of doing the following (eliminating the need for initializing line prior to the while block)? It just seems unnecessary to intialize a variable prior to its usage instead of doing something like while ((String line = br.readLine) != null) {}. If not, why not?

```
BufferedReader reader = null;

try
{
    File file = new File("sample-file.dat");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: there are a lot of things in java that seem unnecessary now.

Comment: perhaps `for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()){...}` will work. Still it's somewhat ugly

Comment: @Vladimir indeed, in fact as its `for(initialisation; condition; incriminent)` I would say this is very appropriate use of tbe for loop

Comment: Still, using a for loop instead of a while loop in this situation seems overkill.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot avoid initializing the variable. However, you can use [Try-With-Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make it a lot cleaner.

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample-file.dat"))) {
    String line;  
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question being asked about variable initialization. However, it does show a cleaner way to write the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding this for completions sake, if anyone is using Java 8, you have access to the [Stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). Using this you can just simply do the following:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(...);

reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
```

And if you're wondering, the code under the hood that produces this **does** check for `null` lines.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't declare (and use) a variable in the while loop expression evaluation step. But, you can eliminate the `finally` block by using a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try (
    File file = new File("sample-file.dat");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I do like the try-with-resources feature in Java 7!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't declare a variable inside the condition definition except in a `for` loop. Can't really say why - perhaps because the condition is not supposed to be somewhere you initialize things, whereas a `for` initialization step is.

But anyway, especially in cases where the loop conditions are complicated, some coders prefer to use

```
while (true) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if ( line == null )
        break;
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

But it's really a matter of style.

Comment: +1 for a different idiom. however I find this particular idiom quite hard to read because i usually look for the conditions under which the loop terminates within the initialization block. this forces me to scan two lines below to locate the terminating condition.

Comment: Yes, @algorithmic, it's usually not a good thing to do in such a simple case. I switch over to this style normally when producing the data for the next step is complicated, and so you end up with one complicated block before the while and one identical one inside it. In that case, if a `do...while` won't do, I prefer using `while(true)`.